# Do Canon's EX-RT speedlights still work with the old optical wireless system?

Tags: canon, hotshoe-flash, wireless-triggers

Canon's latest Speedlites, the [600EX-RT](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/speedlite_flash_lineup/speedlite_600ex_rt) and the just-announced [430EX III-RT](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/speedlite_flash_lineup/speedlite_430ex_iii_rt), can be controlled via radio rather than light to avoid the line of sight requirement that older optically-triggered Speedlights have. Does this make them incompatible with the optical system, or do they work with the optical system too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The 600EX-RT and 430EX III-RT both work with optical triggering** and the newer radio triggering system (although you can only use one system at a time). Chapter 5 in the [600EX-RT manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0300007510/04/600ex-600exrt-im5-en-es-fr.pdf)(pdf) covers setting the 600EX-RT up as either master or slave using optical control. There manual for the 430EX III-RT isn't available yet, but the product page tells us:

> When used with a compatible flash, or flash driver mounted on camera,
>   the Speedlite 430EX III-RT **can serve as a slave unit in an optical
>   setup**, at distances of up to 49.2 ft./15m (indoors). In addition to
>   optical wireless flash, the Speedlite 430EX III-RT is capable of radio
>   transmitted wireless flash where the flash units need not be in visual
>   proximity to one another and transmission distance is extended up to
>   98.4 ft./30m.

Comment: It's important to note that you can only use either optical or radio. Not both together, so if you're mixing old and new you're stuck with optical and its limitations.

Comment: @alex Great point. Added a clarification.